# Excel formula calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to, in a cell calculate an amount based on a 15minute interval for a hourly travelling rate, i.e. Labour rate is 300 per hour and should it be 15 min 30 min 45 min 60min 105 min or 120 min etc.
Q - how do I do the step by step formula that I can use in seperate cells for this as each cell will be different according to the 15 minute increment rate charged.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it. Currently your question does not show any effort of finding the solution by yourself.

Comment: `=A1+TIMEVALUE("00:15")`, `=A2+TIMEVALUE("00:15")`, `=A3+TIMEVALUE("00:15")`, etc. -or- `=A1+0.01041667`, `=A2+0.01041667`, `=A3+0.01041667`, etc.?

Comment: Can you show us a simple sample and the result that you want? Maybe you need the Int and Mod functions to calculate how many 15 minutes.